# Unable to delete an object in a realm database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm unable to delete an object in a realm database: I have following exception:

```
0x108196d6f:  movq   0x202112(%rip), %rcx      ; "exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:"
0x108196d76:  leaq   0x1e6d0b(%rip), %rdx      ; @"RLMException"
0x108196d7d:  leaq   0x1e71c4(%rip), %rbx      ; @"Unable to delete an object not persisted in this Realm."
```

The record is in the database when I check with realm browser!!! Who had the same problem?

this is my code:

```
func deleteDatabase() {
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    for result in deleteUoMArray {
        var item = result as UoM
        var uomObject = UnitOfMeasurement()
        uomObject.guid = item.guid
        uomObject.unitOfMeasurement = item.unitOfMeasurement
        uomObject.selected = item.selected
        uomObject.index = item.index
        realm.deleteObject(uomObject)
    }
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to delete all objects in the database, as the name of the `deleteDatabase` function would imply, all you need to do is call:

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.deleteAllObjects()
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Otherwise, if `deleteUoMArray` is an `Array`, `RLMResults`, or `RLMArray` of objects to delete, you can call `realm.deleteObjects(deleteUoMArray)`.

Comment: My goal is to delete objects in the Array. The realm.deleteObjects(deleteUoMArray) build with RLMObjects of UoM has the same issue.

Comment: Don't make an array of new UoM objects... Use a query and delete the resulting RLMResults

Comment: @segiddins I have a question somewhat similar to this one. Would you be willing to have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423859/cant-delete-realm-database-objects-from-another-thread-even-after-searching