# Can't delete Realm database objects from another thread (even after searching)

Tags: ios, realm

I'm having a similar problem as the poster in this thread:
[Unable to delete an object in a realm database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243034/unable-to-delete-an-object-in-a-realm-database)

I have an array of RLMObject subclasses created from a search on a queue called 'syncQueue'. It's a bunch of Diagnostic objects that need to be sent up to the server.

These objects are packaged up and sent up to the server using the [Google Client Library for iOS](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/). Once the library returns that the objects have been successfully uploaded, I want to delete them out of Realm. I grab some samples out of Realm.

```
NSArray *samples = [someClass getMySamplesFromRealm];
```

So now I have an array of samples. ^^This happens on the 'syncQueue', which uses its own thread. Still on the same thread, we package and upload the samples. So there's a callback block that looks something like this:

```
GTLServiceTicket *ticket = [service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error)
    {
        [syncHandler removeTicket:ticket];
        if( error )
        {
            // Handle Error
        }
        else
        {
            [diagDataAccessManager deleteObjects:samples];
        }
    }];
```

Here is the code that deletes these objects.

```
1  - (void)deleteObjects:(NSArray *)samples
2  {
3      if (samples.count > 0) 
4      {
5          [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] beginWriteTransaction];
6          for (Diagnostic *diagnostic in samples) 
7          {
8              Diagnostic *diagnosticToDelete = [Diagnostic objectForPrimaryKey:diagnostic.primaryId];
9              [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] deleteObject:diagnosticToDelete];
10         }
11         [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] commitWriteTransaction];
12     }
13     
14 }
```

So I'm trying to do a search before I do a delete. However...

On line 8, I get an exception: **"Realm accessed from incorrect thread"** Now, I assume this is because when I run `Diagnostic objectForPrimaryKey:`, it's trying to use the Realm associated with the `*diagnostic` object, which was created on another thread.

My question is: how on Earth can I delete these specific objects, if I can't look at them to figure out *which* specific objects they are?

Any clarification/advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best will probably be to pass the primary keys to the new thread, rather than the objects.

Comment: I was leaning that way. Ok. I can accept that. Thanks!